# How to detect in user clicked on "Next" in their keyboard on a form input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to detect the event that happens when a user is focused on an input and clicks on "Next" in the keyboard.

```
event.keyCode == 13
```

did not work for me

[image]

Comment: You can try to get the keycode with keycode event. Look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp

Comment: can you post the code where you check the event keycode?

Comment: https://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html